# Creating data bars or conditional formatting in Excel

Tags: excel, graph

[image]

Is there a way to create a visual graph/data bar, etc. that would compare five categories line by line (Unleased, Occupied, Leased, Construction Leased, Construction unleased) against "Max RSF" and show coloring based on its value comparison?

I tried looking into some of the things Excel has to offer, but could not figure out how it is done in a different column and for multiple categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do that using stacked bar graphs in Excel. Look at the screenshot.

Select your data and insert a stacked bar chart as shown in the screenshot and apply colors according to your requirements. Also you may need to adjust the x axis in reverse order and cross at max etc.

[image: Select data and insert a stacked bar chart]

[image: Final view can be improved more]
You can not use conditional formatting easily to obtain a graph like you mentioned. Because some times you have more than one value in a row(example: you have "Construction Leased" and "Construction Unleased" to show in one bar).

Here your Y axis(value axis) range is automatic. But you have to write some vba codes to update the axis max value and other axis settings if you need more customized axis view.